# How to increase the loading time of the website

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

Where can i add the below code in my WordPress theme.

```
window.onLoad(){
  $import('base.js');

}

function $import(src){
  var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElem.setAttribute('src',src);
  scriptElem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElem);
}
```

Comment: you means delay at starting

Comment: use jquery delay **https://api.jquery.com/delay/**

Comment: Thank u! I will try.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66946/script-to-run-at-completion-of-page-loading

Answer (score 0):

you can add the jquery scripts right in footer.php file of your folder. as you know footer.php is loaded on all pages. it will run automatically.
can u plz share more details about the scenario, i might be able to provide you the code exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your response